# Ground plane size of microstrip

Tags: rf, microstrip

I am trying to design an rf mems switch whose conpcept is shown in the image.

[image]

I am thinking to use microstrip for transmission of signal. Is there any recommendation for minimum width of ground plane of microstrip? Something like 5*w

Comment: I'm confused: the point of the M like micro in MEMS is that things are significantly smaller than wavelength. So, hm, are you sure you'll actually have to deal with what is usually understood when one says "microstrip line" on your die? I'm also no expert in MEMS manufacturing, but wouldn't the whole substrate be glued to a metal plane, anyway?

Comment: What frequencies are you talking about here?  MHz?  GHz?  Tens of GHz?